# Исключение из индексации товаров, которых нет на складе в 1C Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, поиск, индексация

Приветствую. Есть такая проблема в битриксе - есть поиск по заголовкам search.title. Нужно, чтобы он не индексировал товары, торговых предложений которых нет на складах. Написал код на тестовой странице, вбиваю ID товара вручную - все показывает верно, есть ли наличие ТП и все вроде хорошо. Ну а затем в init.php вызываю событие перед индексацией и тем же образом пытаюсь исключить ненужные товары, но все равно они как-то проходят. В чем может быть проблема?

```
AddEventHandler("search", "BeforeIndex", "BeforeIndexHandler");
function BeforeIndexHandler($arFields)
{
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
CModule::IncludeModule('catalog');      
$TovarExist = false;
$TypeProduct = CCatalogSKU::getOffersList($arFields['ID']);
if($TypeProduct != false){ 
    foreach($TypeProduct as $key => $ProdSku){              
        foreach($ProdSku as $key => $SkuID){                
            for ($i = 2; $i < 12; $i++) {
                if ($i !== 8 && $i !== 9) { // неактивные склады
                $rsStore = CCatalogStoreProduct::GetList(array(), array('PRODUCT_ID' =>$SkuID['ID'], 'STORE_ID' => $i), false, false, array());
                $arStore = $rsStore->Fetch();
                    if($arStore['AMOUNT'] > 0){
                        $TovarExist = true;
                    }
                }
            }                            
        }
    }       

}
if($TovarExist === false){ 
        $arFields["BODY"] = $arFields["TITLE"] = '';
        unset($arFields["BODY"]); //на всякий случай
        unset($arFields["TITLE"]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением `$arFields["TAGS"] = '';`

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых: обработчику надо передавать `&$arFields`. 
Во-вторых вы бегаете по циклу устанавливая флаг, а проверяете его когда выпадаетее из цикла, то есть вы работаете только с последним значением флага. 
Мне почему-то кажется, что должно быть так:

```
...    
if ($arStore['AMOUNT'] < 0) { 
    $arFields['BODY'] = $arFields['TITLE'] = ''; 
    unset($arFields['BODY'], $arFields['TITLE']);
}
...
```

В `unset` можно передавать любое кол-во аргументов. и сокращаем кол-во обрабатываемых условий. 
Для обработки складов тоже можно сделать упрощение. Уберите к черту `for`. Создайте массив со складами. 
Можете даже сформировать его с помощью API выбрав только активные склады `CCatalogStore::GetList(array(), array("ACTIVE" => "Y"), array('ID')`, ну или как-то так, вот [дока](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/classes/ccatalogstore/getlist.php).
И через `in_array()` проверяйте. `if` работает быстрее чем `for`. Чем меньше циклов, тем быстрее выполняется скрипт.

Comment: Во-первых, ваш совет не помог, во-вторых, оптимизаций скрипта я занимаюсь уже после того, как он начинает работать, по этому поводу я ничего не спрашивал. В-третьих, если бы вы внимательней разобрались со скриптом, то увидели бы, что флаг устанавливается ТОЛЬКО тогда, когда на каком-то складе есть торговое предложение в наличии, в противном случае флаг не устанавливается, что мне и нужно было.

Comment: Флаг совершенно бесполезен.Проще сразу в цикле проверять на меньше и сразу выполнять действие, зачем в обратном случае ставить флаг, а потом все равно выполнять нужное действие. С флагом получается 2 лишних действия. Оптимизацией нужно заниматься сразу еще до написания кода. Структура алгоритма должна быть оптимальна без действий которые в общем-то никак не влияют на его работу. В Вашем случае такое действие установка флага. Ну и получить нужные ID складов можно через API. Но это Ваше дело.

Comment: И какое действие предлагаете " сразу в цикле" выполнять? Если на одном складе нет, то сразу вычеркивать из индексации или как?

Comment: Зачем же на одном. Вы можете сразу проверять наличие товара на всех нужных складах. В `CCatalogStoreProduct::GetList` передавайте в фильтр `PRODUCT_ID` и `=AMOUNT=>0`. Пусть он возвращает только идентификаторы складов. А затем через считайте сколько там складов Вам вернуло. Если все склады попали, то вычеркивайте сразу ин индексации, если не все, тогда оставляйте. Нет смысла перебирать склады. Или передавайте в `CCatalogStoreProduct::GetList` в фильтр еще и массив нужных складов. Нет смысла по-складово перебирать.

Comment: А, все, понял, годная идея, спасибо :)